# What to regress in a Difference-in-Differences method?

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

I am currently using the [Difference-in-Differences method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_in_differences) to test my hypothesis, which is as follows:

> The Milk Scandal in 2008 has had a significant effect on the Consumer Price Index of Milk products in China.

I have a control group, which is the CPI for 'Flavourings'. Now I want to do a regression, but I am not sure where my data should be inserted.

My model is as follows:

$$ 
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 D_{\text{milk}} + \beta_2 D_{\text{post-scandal}} + \beta_3 D_{\text{milk}}D_{\text{post-scandal}} + \varepsilon 
$$

In this model, is the Y a matrix with both my CPI variable data?

Comment: No, it is a vector where the data is stacked.